# MS UnitTest - Private Accessor not always recognized

Tags: .net, unit-testing

This problem doesn't occur in all projects, hence it makes it even more frustrating.

If I click on a Private method to create a unit test, it would generate a TestProject assembly and create a predefined class in there.  It would also create a Accessor for that class.

```
[TestMethod()]
        [DeploymentItem("xxx.Client.dll")]
        public void PopulateIncomeCostsDataSetTest()
        {
            CashFlowOperations_Accessor target = new CashFlowOperations_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            CashflowModel cashflowModel = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            CashflowDataSet ds = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            target.PopulateIncomeCostsDataSet(cashflowModel, ds);
            Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
        }
```

As long as I create this unit test for private methods in a library assembly (dll) its all fine, but if I create it for a Console application where `[DeploymentItem("xxx.exe")]` is an executable, my Accessor stays in red color and I cant access the internal private methods of that accessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be a bug in Visual Studio.  This can happen in VS 2088 and even VS 2010.  The SP1 for VS 2010 solved this problem for me.  Hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps (I haven't been able to reproduce your error) but in Local.testsettings there is an option to enable deployment.

- Open Local.testsettings from Solution Items
- Select "Deployment" item in listbox
- Check "Enable deployment"

This must be done before you can unit test in applications instead of libraries

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just double checked it and it is already checked. I have no idea why that is like this. :(